# How do the solid OpenGL lights found in the system preferences work?

Tags: customization

Where can I find a detailed explanation of this topic ?

For example, where the lights are located, which type of lights they are, which is the illumination model, etc.

Comment: You could start with this - "The first is the key light on the left, and the second is a dimmer full light from the right.A third light is also available, which by default is set to provide highlights from the lower right." From book  "Mastring Blender" by Tony Mallen, https://goo.gl/cI2DfJ.

Answer (score 1):

All three are directional lights with the direction relative to the view angle (think sun lamps parented to the camera). The direction is controlled via the direction widget:

[image]

There are no differences between the three AFAIK, three was just the number chosen to be hardcoded in.

They will add to each other when their areas of illumination overlap.

Comment: What are AFAIK ?

Comment: @Valerio AFAIK = As far as I know